# alternating MySQLdb import error

Tags: mysql, linux, cluster-computing, sungridengine

We are using SGE cluster.
From time to time i'm getting the error below. This happens when I'm running the same script multiple times at once (using the cluster) on different input files.
Do you have a clue on what's causing it?
If I run it again, I won't get this error...

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/groups/pupko/mosheein/pupkoSVN/trunk/scripts/ploiDB/buildGeneraTree.py", line 10, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```